# Google sheets query how to percentage pie chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How to write Google Charts query for a pie chart, which shows percentage of every string counted in a column?

Google Charts Query language reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

What I tried and didn't work:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT count(B) pivot B');
```

Here are the table and chart examples:

[image: Example table]
[image]